# Set options for single instance of an Angular Toastr?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toastr, angular-toastr

I am using Angular JS 1.4.1 and Angular Toastr 1.7.0.

Most of the toastrs in my app are the default top right, and work fine.

However, I want to call ONE with the `positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width'` and I can't get it to work.  It still opens at the defaults set it my app config.

```
   $scope.tabLeave = function () {
    toastr.warning('Warning', 'You have unsaved data.', {
      closeButton: true,
      positionClass: 'toast-top-full-width'
    });
  };
```

What am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr), it seems that property cannot be overridden in a toast, but will be changed in a future version:

> FAQ
>
> Q: Why can't I override the positionClass in a toast? It gets ignored.
>   A: The toasts don't have a position, they are attached to a container
>   and is that container who has the position set on the page. This will
>   be changed in a future version.

Comment: Which is odd, since the docs for Angular Toastr seem to say you can, which is why I did what I did:  `toastr.info('What a nice apple button', 'Button spree', {
  closeButton: true,
  closeHtml: '<button></button>'
});`

Comment: Of course, now I see the caveat about the ONE thing I am trying to override.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
this.toastr.info('No credit remaining', '', { disableTimeOut: true, closeButton: true });
```